# VsCode WebView update cause cursor to blink

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have custom WebView extension for VS Code that is updated whenever some internal value changes and unfortunately cursor icon 'blinks'(~switches there and back between arrow and beam icon) whenever WebView is updated and cursor is located in editable document. Is there anything i can do to prevent that from happening?[Gif of blinking cursor here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp28R.gif)

My code looks like this

```
class LiveVariableViewProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
... 
public updateWebview()
{
    const val : string = getHtmlForWebview();
    if (val!=this._view.webview.html)
    {
        this._view.webview.html = val; //causes cursor to 'blink'
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I dont know why the cursor is blinking when html string is assigned but possible workaround is to update the values inside the generated html using java script:

```
let element = document.getElementById( myElemementId);
if (element )
{
    element.textContent = `${newValue} `;
}
```